# selecting multiple svg elements and dragging them in Raphael.js

Tags: svg, selection, raphael, drag

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

I basically have an svg document with multiple shapes,lines,text,etc... and I am trying to implement a selection tool which helps me select multiple elements, group them and drag them.

Answer (score 27):

There is a feature in raphäel called set: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#set

You can add all the elements you want to drag around to a new set and then apply the dragging mechanism to the set.

I made you this: http://jsfiddle.net/Wrajf/

It's not perfect. I would add the mousemove event to the document, but for that you need a library like jQuery. Otherwise if you move the mouse to fast you have a fall out.

Comment: I feel ya, monkee. So much effort put in to this answer only to see it disregarded by the asker.

Answer (score 4):

I did this ([example here](http://jsfiddle.net/z3Vj2/1/)) :

EDIT : something cleaner

1. Create methods to set and retrieve the group of an element :

   ```
   Raphael.el.setGroup = function (group) {
     this.group = group;
   };
   Raphael.el.getGroup = function () {
     return this.group;
   };
   ```
2. Create the method of your grouped elements :

   ```
   Raphael.fn.superRect = function (x, y, w, h, text) {
     var background = this.rect(x, y, w, h).attr({
       fill: "#FFF",
       stroke: "#000",
       "stroke-width": 1
     });
     var label = this.text(x+w/2,y+h/2, text);
     var layer = this.rect(x, y, w, h).attr({
       fill: "#FFF",
       "fill-opacity": 0,
       "stroke-opacity": 0,
       cursor: "move"
     });
     var group = this.set();
     group.push(background, label, layer);
     layer.setGroup(group);
     return layer;
   };
   ```
3. create functions to drag a grouped elements :

   ```
   var dragger = function () {
     this.group = this.getGroup();
     this.previousDx = 0;
     this.previousDy = 0;
   },
   move = function (dx, dy) {
     var txGroup = dx-this.previousDx;
     var tyGroup = dy-this.previousDy;

     this.group.translate(txGroup,tyGroup);

     this.previousDx = dx;
     this.previousDy = dy;
   },
   up = function () {};
   ```
4. Init SVG paper and create your elements (the order of element is important)::

   ```
   window.onload = function() {

     var paper = Raphael(0, 0,"100%", "100%");

     var x=50, y=50, w=30, h=20;

     paper.superRect(x, y, w, h, "abc").drag(move, dragger, up);

     x +=100;

     paper.superRect(x, y, w, h, "def").drag(move, dragger, up);

   };
   ```