# How can I make rectangle selection on multiple nodes with graph dracula?

Tags: javascript, graph, nodes

I am working on some graph visualizations, and I am using the JavaScript library [graph Dracula](http://www.graphdracula.net/). Now, with this library, when I want to move a node I have to click the node I want to move and move it on the desired place (with drag and drop).  But, what I want to do is to select more nodes and move all of them. I can't figure out how to do this, since I am not so experienced in JavaScript programming. So, my question is:

1. How can I select multiple nodes with rectangle selection and move
   them?
2. How can I select multiple nodes with, say, Ctrl + left click and select more nodes and then move them?

Answer (score 6):

By the looks of things, almost all of `Dracula's` graph rendering is really managed by [`RaphaelJS`](http://raphaeljs.com/).

In which case, things may be quite a bit easier for you. It seems [other people have asked how to move elements in RaphaelJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844927/selecting-multiple-svg-elements-and-dragging-them-in-raphael-js).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @NT3RP, but this answers my question partially (here it is shown for all the elements, not for selected ones). Any idea how can I modify this? (BTW, +1 for the answer!)